# How Can I found Xpath when clicking on a button a row is added to the JQGrid

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, junit

I am trying to find the Xpath for the Row which I was added on clicking a button. In the first row and first column I need to click on datepicker and select the date. How can I find the Xpath for this element of date picker. Below is my Code

```
        `<table id="list" class="ui-jqgrid-btable" cellspacing="0" 
         cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border: 0px none ! important; 
         width: 2205px;" tabindex="0" role="grid" aria-multiselectable="false" aria-labelledby="gbox_list">
         <tbody>
        <tr class="jqgfirstrow" style="height:auto" role="row">
        <td style="height:0px;width:100px;" role="gridcell"></td>
        <td style="height:0px;width:70px;" role="gridcell"></td>
        <td style="height:0px;width:120px;" role="gridcell"></td>
        <td style="height:0px;width:200px;" role="gridcell"></td>
        <td style="height:0px;width:120px;" role="gridcell"></td>
        <td style="height:0px;width:140px;" role="gridcell"></td>
        <td style="height:0px;width:65px;" role="gridcell"></td>
        <td style="height:0px;width:65px;" role="gridcell"></td>
        <td style="height:0px;width:70px;" role="gridcell"></td>
        <td style="height:0px;width:160px;" role="gridcell"></td>
        <td style="height:0px;width:70px;" role="gridcell"></td>
        <td style="height:0px;width:160px;" role="gridcell"></td>
        <td style="height:0px;width:170px;" role="gridcell"></td>
        <td style="height:0px;width:100px;" role="gridcell"></td>
        <td style="height:0px;width:100px;" role="gridcell"></td>
        <td style="height:0px;width:130px;" role="gridcell"></td>
        <td style="height:0px;width:70px;" role="gridcell"></td>
        <td style="height:0px;width:130px;" role="gridcell"></td>
        <td style="height:0px;width:70px;" role="gridcell"></td>
        <td style="height:0px;width:150px;display:none;" role="gridcell"></td>
       </tr>  
       <tr id="1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr   ui-state- 
       highlight disableRow" tabindex="0" role="row" aria-selected="true"
       editable="1">
       <td rowspan="1" aria-describedby="list_effectiveDate" style="" role="gridcell">
       <input id="1_effectiveDate" class="editable hasDatepicker border-
       red" type="text" name="effectiveDate" style="width: 98%;"  role="textbox" readonly="readonly"></td>
```

`

I tried below code:

```
      `driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='1']/td[1]")).toString();
       driver.findElement(By.id("1_effectiveDate")).click();
       driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/a")).click();`
```

Comment: Unclear what you mean. Are you writing some sort of bot/reader, which needs to find a certain control and emulate a click on it? 
Please provide a bit more context.

Comment: Yes. I have to select and click on it. I am trying to find the Xpath for [ id="1_effectiveDate"]. It is date picker with is default for JQgrid. it is input field. I have to select the date in date picker.    I tried below xpath:                               driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='1']/td[1]")).toString();
    driver.findElement(By.id("1_effectiveDate")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/a")).click();

Comment: Would JQuery be an option? Then you could skip the XPath and work with the DOM elements using JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Would JQuery be an option? Then you could skip the XPath and work with the DOM elements using JQuery.

Also, check if you REALLY must click the calendar? Couldn't you just provide it with the value of your choice? From the looks of it it uses a text field as backing. If you only find out which format it stores the date in, you should be able to add the value directly to that textbox without need to emulate clicks and stuff.

Comment: As per Design We are able to select the date only by calendar. No Input text box is provided. They used default date picker in JQGrid Table.

Comment: Is JQuery an option?